# Access GeoJSON property of a filtered Feature, before creating a layer with it

Tags: expression, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

## Background:

I'm loading markers into a Mapbox map, either manually and either from geodata properties.
The GeoJSON Points get displayed as markers and all is good with it.

- **first** I provide a URL to GeoJSON-data, and add it as source (`map.addSource('layer1', {type: 'geojson', data: geojsonURL ..}`)
- **then** I `map.addLayer` & specify filter-expression and style for visualization.

## Problem:

the markers **should show a custom image, that is specified inside the `properties` of the corresponding GeoJSON *Point Feature***, like:

```js
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    28.303157,
                    32.553093
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Marker title used in the popup",
                "image": "https:\/\/my.host.com\/custom_icon.png"    // this URL should be used as marker custom icon
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

<sup>(Geodata referenced by `geojsonURL`)</sup>

The issue is that Mapbox **requires all the images to be "pre-loaded" before usage**, via something like
`map.loadImage(geojsonURL, (err, img) => { map.addImage('markerImage1', img) })`
but I get to know the image URL only **after the feature has been filtered** (while executing `map.addLayer`) and I don't know when to preload the URL!

So I end up in a chicken-egg problem:

- I need the image URL, for preloading it into the map
- but I cannot access the `properties` of the specifically filtered feature *before* the Mapbox expression is executed:

```js
map.addLayer({
    id: 'foobarMarker',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'foobarMarker',
    filter: ["all", ["==","$type","Point"]],
    layout: {
        // `mycustomicon` should have value 'markerImage1', as specified during the `addImage` step.
        'icon-image': mycustomicon,
        'visibility': 'visible'
    }
})
```

Feature `filter` and `layout` styling are done in the same function call (`addLayer`), but `layout.icon-image` needs to already know the image name added when preloading the URL (from `feature.properties.image`).

## Question:

how can I access the `properties.image` value for the filtered Feature, so I can resolve the value for `mycustomicon`, to then pass it to the layer/marker creation?

---

**EDIT:** trying to expand on the issue.

One approach is to

1. pre-fetch the `geojsonURL`
2. `JSON.parse(it)`
3. filter all the Point features
4. fetch each image URL with `loadImage(imageURL)`
5. add it with `addImage('label', image)`
   But this feels ugly and duplicates the work, as `addSource` & `addFilter` already do Fetch, JsonParse and Filter.
   I just want to fetch the imageURL and make it available to mapbox (step 4 & 5).

Another (ideal?) approach would be to have support for callbacks in Mapbox Expressions.
*If it would be possible* to use a callback with Mapbox expressions (after the Feature has been filtered), I would access the URL (via `filteredFeature.properties.image`) and pre-load it with `loadImage`.

Something like:

```js
map.addLayer({
    id: 'foobarMarker',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'foobarMarker',
    filter: ["all", ["==","$type","Point"]],
    layout: {
        'icon-image': (feature) => {
            await map.loadImage(
                feature.properties.image,
                (err, img) => map.addImage('markerImage1', img)
            )
            return 'markerImage1';
        },
        'visibility': 'visible'
    }
})
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do, or what you mean by "at filtering time", or what the value of `mycustomicon` would be. Would using a data-driven property, like `image: ['get','icon-image']` work?

Comment: Maybe is a typo, do you rather mean `'icon-image': ['get', 'image']`? If yes, it is what I wanted to do, but I would need to run `map.loadImage` with the value from `['get','image']`, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I tried to expand & clarify the question, please let me know if it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understand your question, it comes down to: You're loading a GeoJSON, where each feature has a property specifying the URL of the icon image that should be used to represent it. (I don't understand what "filtering" has to do with anything in this problem statement.)

The way I would handle this:

1. First, load the GeoJSON object outside of Mapbox, using plain old `window.fetch()`.
2. Now, iterate over the features, making a dictionary of icons you need to load, and giving an icon name for each icon (rather than just its url):

```js
const icons = {}
for (const feature of mygeojson.features) {
   if (!icons[feature.properties.image]) {
      icons[feature.properties.image] = `icon-${Object.keys(icons).length}`;
   }
   feature.properties.icon = icons[feature.properties.image]
}
```

3. Load the icons:

```js
for (const url of Object.keys(icons)) {
   map.loadImage(url, (error, image) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    map.addImage(icons[url], image);
});
```

4. Use your modified geojson in your style:

```js
map.addSource('foobarMarker', {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: mygeojson
});
```

5. Add a layer referencing the new `icon` property:

```js
map.addLayer({
    id: 'foobarMarker',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'foobarMarker',
    filter: ["all", ["==","$type","Point"]],
    layout: {
        'icon-image': ['get', 'icon'],
        'visibility': 'visible'
    }
})
```